# R language：grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, invalid input 'x坐标' in 'utf8towcs'

Tags: r, ggplot2, character-encoding, jetbrains-ide

### My IDE

Jetbrains DataSpell

### My R Version

R 4.0.2

### My R code

> I used Chinese in the parameter "xlab"

```
x <- -6:6
y <- x^3
library("ggplot2")
qplot(x,y, xlab = "x坐标")
```

### Error

I used the `qplot()` function of the R language and encountered the following errors:

`grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  中的错误 (DataFrames.R#23): invalid input 'x坐标' in 'utf8towcs'`

> When I change the Chinese in the parameters to English, It will become normal

**I seem to have found some problems, I can use Chinese parameters on RGUI and RStudio, and I can assign Chinese to variables without any errors, but on Jetbrains DataSpell IDE there are always errors**

Comment: This has nothing to do with python.

Answer (score 0):

After putting space after x and the Chinese characters every thing goes correct see :

```r
library("ggplot2")

x <- -6:6
y <- x^3
qplot(x,y, xlab = "x 坐标")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I seem to have found some problems, I can use Chinese parameters on RGUI and RStudio, and I can assign Chinese to variables without any errors, but on Jetbrains DataSpell IDE there are always errors.